# ThreadPoolExecutor to handle high Memory Tasks in Grails?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, grails, grails-2.0

I have some jobs that process images for my application. They take a lot of Heap memory. Thus I want to restrict the number of image processing tasks or queue them in some way.

I also use [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) to handle the image processing, but with my approach sometimes to many worker threads are open concurrently.

How can I use a ThreadPoolExecutor in Grails to get this done right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u can do this by using GParsExecutorsPool

```
    GParsExecutorsPool.withPool() {
    Closure longLastingCalculation = {calculate()}
    Closure fastCalculation = longLastingCalculation.async()  //create a new closure, which starts the original closure on a thread pool
    Future result=fastCalculation()                           //returns almost immediately
    //do stuff while calculation performs …
    println result.get()
}
```

For more details check this link:
[Use of ThreadPool - the Java Executors' based concurrent collection processor](http://www.gpars.org/guide/ref/ThreadPool/Usage.html)